# Can I run unit tests on a deployed app package in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, dotfuscator

The question pretty much explains it. We have a WinRT (Metro) app package that we're obfuscating with Dotfuscator after every build. Because of the way Dotfuscator does renaming, we're required as of right now to manually rename any control that we've called by name from the Codebehind. If we don't, we get a NullReferenceException. This is a bit of annoyance, but we've kept up with it successfully and caught all instances of this, but it's quite time consuming and there's always the chance that we'll miss one.

What I'd love to do is to be able to create some unit tests to test event functionality in the views I've created, but this only works if I can do it in the obfuscated version. I know that we can debug a deployed app package, even debugging obfuscated app packages (since we have the .pdb files in the project).

If anyone has any experience with this or with Dotfuscator and knows a better way of doing this, I'd love to get some input. I could theoretically also create a test that reads in our current 'reference' Dotfuscator project and compares this to all named controls in the codebehind, but that seems like a demon of a test to write, and I don't look forward to having to parse the code-behinds at all. It may be as simple (for varying definitions of simple) as doing a text search on the whole XAML document for the [x:Name"*"] attribute, then searching for the starred value in both the code behind and the Dotfuscator project document, which is thankfully just XML.

Any help you can provide on this would be much appreciated. I've already created a topic on the PreEmptive support forums. I am using Dotfuscator Professional (not the App Store version), and have updated to the most recent version, 4.10.

*Edit 25/4/13
So in the end, while @ianschol 's advice was helpful, for now I implemented the solution I outlined above:
-Enumerate the control's fields
-Determine which fields are properties and which are named controls
-Read in the .xaml.cs
-Find all fields referenced by name, save them

> Note: I then used some Regex to filter out fields declared in the .cs file itself, as they were unnecessary.

-Read in the Dotfuscator project file
-Parse Descendants. If the name of the control shows up in the reference list, assert it has a descendent element with the given name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and reusable technique to solve your issue would probably be to write a helper class that handles reading the property name mappings, and provides a "GetProperty" method to be used by your unit tests.  That way, you can encapsulate fallback behavior that tries the non-obfuscated name if the obfuscated name fails, saving yourself the hassle of worrying about whether or not property name obfuscation is turned on.  There isn't currently a PreEmptive-built solution or tool to perform the translation, but it should be straightforward to build.

Alternatively, you can set up a build that doesn't obfuscate property names in Dotfuscator, and use that for tests.  Personally, I feel that the helper object is easier to work with, but it's also introducing a build system artifact into your code base.

Comment: Note though that with this method, you'd have to wrap it in `#ifdef RELEASE` blocks or some such because otherwise you're giving any attackers a 1 to 1 mapping of unobfuscated to obfuscated names.

Comment: I have successfully done this before though, but as a post-build step using Mono.Cecil for IL replacement